# Offered job but still awaiting offer letter, follow-up then informed that it will be issued based on the result after after a 3rd interview

Tags: job-offer, new-job

I have went through the 2nd interview and was being offered the job verbally. They told me will receive the offer letter within a week and there will be a 3rd interview (just formality) according to procedure.After a week when I follow-up then they informed me that the offer letter could only issued after the result of the 3rd interview. The 3rd interview will be after 3 weeks more but not confirmed. Please advise the reason they are delaying my hiring ? are they interviewing another candidate?

Comment: You haven't been hired nor has an offer been extended. While it's likely you will get the formal job offer, until you sign it and actually show up for the first day, it can be withdrawn in most cases.  You should take the third round of interviews like they are the first.

Answer (score 9):

> Please advise the reason they are delaying my hiring

They've already done that: *An offer is issued after three interviews*

The 3rd interview requirement might be a formality, or they're stalling to interview other candidates, or any number of things, **none of which matter**. You don't have an offer letter so you don't have a job offer. Keep calm and keep looking for a job.

Comment: More importantly, don't resign from your current job (if you have one) until you have the offer letter in hand! Nothing is definite until you have that letter.

Comment: thank u for all the advise. so it's not been confirmed anyway...really has to keep looking but it's hard nowadays where I'm currently quite desperate.